# Why is my Python prime number checker not working?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, numbers

Why is my code below giving me wrong results? When I give it numbers like 2 and 3, it says they're not prime numbers. Only some numbers work but for the most part it gives wrong answers.

```
def prompt_input(input_msg, error_msg):
    while True:
        userinput = input(input_msg)
        try:
            integer = int(userinput)
            if integer > 1:
                return integer
            print(error_msg)
        except ValueError:
            print(error_msg)
    
def check_prime(number):
    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False   
        return True

primenum = prompt_input(
    "Give an integer that's bigger than 1: ",
    "You had one job"
)

if check_prime(primenum):
    print("This is a prime.")
else:
    print("This is not a prime.")
```

Comment: Your `check_prime` function has a for loop, but the loop immediately returns after one iteration.

Comment: This code is written in C, but has the same point in Python. Visit its link and figure it out. https://github.com/dorrinsam/Prime_Numbers/blob/main/main.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to unindent the `return True`.

```
def check_prime(number):
    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False   
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

First issue: Your for loop returns after one iteration, so the correct return logic would be:

```
def check_prime(number):
    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False   
    return True
```

However you are implementing this incorrectly as well, the loop needs to iterate up to the sqrt of the number.

```
def check_prime(number):
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(number))+1):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False   
    return True
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How is looping up to (not including) the number itself incorrect? Slow, yes. Incorrect, no.